# insert or remove a photo from a notebook on demand

Tags: front-end, import, image

I would like a "button" which I could "click on" that would on first click insert a specific photo from a windows file and then, on second click, remove the photo.  It could also be two buttons.  Or some other scheme.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

```
img = Nothing;
Button["Click",
 If[
   ImageQ@img,
   img = Nothing,
   f = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"];
   img = Import[f]];
 ,
 Method -> "Queued"]
Dynamic[If[ImageQ@img, img]]
```

This button will check if `img` is an image, if not it will call the file dialog, import the selected file, and display it - you could change `f` to a fixed filepath if you don't want the dialog. The `Method` parameter is set to "Queued" to allow the dialog. If `img` is an image it will reinitialize `img` to `Nothing`.

Comment: Also you may want to use `SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {"Data", {"Data" -> {"*.png","*.jpg", "*.jpeg"}}}]` to limit the file picker to images.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will try it.